# Could not resolve io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.3

Tags: gradle, micronaut

After creating new application on https://micronaut.io/launch/.
I cannot run it due to exception:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'delivery-tracker-service-v2'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.3.
     Required by:
         project : > io.micronaut.application:io.micronaut.application.gradle.plugin:4.0.3
      > No matching variant of io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.3 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2.1' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.3 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2.1')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.3 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2.1')
```

Comment: Do you use Java 17?

Comment: I think no, I find the problem. Problem in java version. Thx

Comment: Using the IDEA IDE check both you project and Gradle settings - both must use Java 17+.